# CDBStore as persistence storage for CoreData in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data

Here in
[Apple's sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008405-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2/) I found this type of persistence storage.

Can anyone tell me what is CDBStore and
what is the advantage of using CDBStore as persistence storage over other storage types like sqlite, plist etc,

And in which all cases its not using ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CDBStore is an arbitrary file extension.  In reality, it is a SQLite database as evidenced a few lines further when it is read with the parameter `NSSQLiteStoreType`.  The advantages over sqlite are none, the advantages over plist are whatever advantages sqlite has over plist.